# Why does my Photoshop brush have weird tapering compared to other apps like Krita

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, krita

In this image, the left-hand side is me doing standard strokes in Krita with a Wacom CTH-690, compared to doing strokes with the standard brush in Photoshop. Why are the ends of my strokes in Ps not natural-looking like in Krita?

[image: stroke comparison]

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but there are a whole range of different settings available in Photoshop in the *Brush Settings* panel. You might need to experiment with these to the stroke you want. Could have to do with the *Shape Dynamics > Minimum Diameter* setting?

Comment: @Wolff have thought about minimum diameter, and yes it occurred to me that that will make my strokes look better in general, but it doesn't explain the non-linear (or even logarithmic) curve

Comment: Isn't the curve dependent on the pressure you apply? Or rather a combination of your tablet settings (where you can define a pressure curve), your Photoshop settings and how you apply pressure with the pen.

Comment: @Wolff yes definitely, but the left (Krita) shows natural pen lift-off, as in real life. What happens with photoshop isn't the IRL curve

Comment: Are you talking about that very thin ending on some of the strokes? If it's not something that can be fixed with settings what kind of answer are you hoping for? Do you think it's a driver issue? I had problems with PS supporting my Wacom One pressure correctly until I manually created the file `PSUserConfig.txt` in the `AppData > Roaming > Adobe > Adobe Photoshop 2020 > Adobe Photoshop 2020 Settings` folder (on Windows). [Source](https://piceditorreview.com/photoshop-pen-pressure-not-working/). Do you have that file? (It's a long shot )

Comment: I had this issue with my Genius brand tablet, exclusively in Photoshop.  I think @Wolff is right - it's a driver problem.

Comment: @Wolff thanks but that fix didn't change anything. I guess I'll have to try limit by firmness in wacom settings and raise my minimum brush size